# what does tcp:*:port mean in zeromq?

Tags: zeromq

I see this sort of address used in a bunch of examples.  What does it mean exactly?  Does it mean it will connect to any/all machines on the subnet that have something listening to that port?  Or something else entirely?  I see such usage in the docs and in books without explanation.  Sort of annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is explained [in the manual](http://api.zeromq.org/master:zmq-tcp).

ZeroMQ supports multiple *transports*. `tcp` means you are using the TCP transport.

The address (or endpoint) for the TCP transport has the following format:

```
tcp://interface:port
```

When you bind to a local address, *interface* is either the IP address of a specific interface (network) or `*`, which means to listen on all interfaces (networks). *port* is the TCP port or `*` for a random port.

When you connect to a remote endpoint, *interface* is the hostname or IP address of the remote machine. *port* is the TCP port of the remote endpoint.

Comment: D'OH.  Of course.  Forgive the brain fart.

Answer (score 0):

To add to *rveerd*'s answer, what's often missed is that you can multiply bind a socket. So, `tcp://*:5555` specifies port 5555 on any interface and you can bind the socket accordindly. But by calling `zmq_bind()` again you can bind the same socket to, say, `ipc:///tmp/feeds/0`, which means it will also accept connections on the `/tmp/feeds/0` IPC pipe.

This is a pretty spectacularly useful feature in my view, because you can trvially have other actors local and remote to the machine though a single zmq socket.